# AngularJS, best practice for data flow between shopping cart and list of products

Tags: angularjs, scope, cart

in my AngularJS app a have 2 controllers: first for list of products and second for shooping cart. What is the best way to resolve data flow when product is added form list of products to shooping cart or removed from shopping cart and status of it changed on a product list item. Whether to send the product which is added/removed during a given event by service to another controller and modify scope in it. Or better to work on one scope for two controllers and update it by service. Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using service as a medium for communication between controllers. The service would ensure that the state of the data remains intact. Hoping that you are using a separate scope for each controller, the optimal way would be using a service to update the data in the scope.
Another way I would suggest is to use some store (Flux pattern), since you are heavily depending on data present in your scope. The implementation might be a bit hard as you are using Angular 1.x but it is worth the effort.
**PS: would also recommend using a view model instead of using scope directly in your controllers and refraining from using global scope.**

Comment: @Kermit Glad, it helped.